# KeyError, cant find key while sourcing from an api call

Tags: python

Why am I getting a key error? I've checked the [site](https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/29853218.json) already using the first id and it has a "descendants" key. Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ronel_Priela\Desktop\Python\Crash_course\ch17_working_w_api\hn_submissions.py", line 24, in <module>
    'comments': id_dictionary['descendants'],
KeyError: 'descendants'
```

Here's my code:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import requests

#API call
url = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code)

#Storing response
response_dicts = r.json()

#Calling another API for each id
dictionary_profiles = []
for id in response_dicts[:30]:
    url = f"https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/{id}.json"
    r=requests.get(url)
    id_dictionary = r.json()
    print(f'ID: {id} Status: {r.status_code}')

    ##Create dictionary profiles for each id
    dictionary_profile = {
        'title': id_dictionary['title'],
        'hn_link': f"https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id={id}",
        'comments': id_dictionary['descendants'],
    }
    dictionary_profiles.append(dictionary_profile)

print(dictionary_profiles)
```

Here is a result of printing id_dictionary, I got what I expected.

```
{'by': 'signa11', 'descendants': 5, 'id': 29860951, 'kids': [29861081, 29861176, 29861155, 29861086, 29861179], 'score': 13, 'time': 1641711518, 'title': 'Literate programming: Knuth is doing it wrong (2014)', 'type': 'story', 'url': 'http://akkartik.name/post/literate-programming'}
```

Comment: When i go to [this site](https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/29856193.json) I see no `descendants` key

Comment: How? This is the site: https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/"{id}".json and this is one of the ids: 29853362

Comment: id_dictionary is linked to this url "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/"{id}".json" not the one with ycombinator

Comment: can you print `id_dictionary` and provide it in the question. Make sure that response you receive in code is what you expect.

Comment: @K450 posted, I received a correct output from my id_dictionary it has descendants in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following website does not have `'descendants'` key (this is the 27th website on the list):

```
url = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/29856193.json"
```

The contents are:

> {"by":"festinalente","id":29856193,"score":1,"time":1641675620,"title":"Finley
> (YC W21) is hiring in Eng and Sales to launch fintech
> infrastructure","type":"job","url":"https://www.finleycms.com/careers/"}

You can use `dict.get` method to avoid getting any error. The `dict.get` method returns the value for the specified key if the key is in the dictionary; if not, it returns None by default. So if you change the code that constructs `dictionary_profile` as below, your code will work without errors (the websites where there are no `'title'` or `'descendants'` keys will have None at those keys in `dictionary_profile`).

```
dictionary_profile = {
        'title': id_dictionary.get('title'),
        'hn_link': f"https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id={id}",
        'comments': id_dictionary.get('descendants'),
    }
```

Comment: I see so even if one item has no key I get a key error even if all the other ones are good?

Comment: @RonelPriela Yes. You have a list of site urls that you get the contents of and it turns out the 27th didn't have your wanted key.

Comment: man, thanks a lot for checking each URL, the book solution did not even use a get method for it.